# How to get all trainings from Google Fit using REST API?

Tags: google-fit-api

I wanted to get automatically tracked trainings (eg you don't open Google Fit on your phone but you went for a walk and it's visible in your journal as "morning walk") trough Google Fit REST API. I used `https://fitness.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions` request but all I get in response is Zepp Life data that does not show in Google Fit app

```
{
  "deletedSession": [], 
  "nextPageToken": "XmRh5uKh1SZxkLjWziJjZQ", 
  "session": [
    {
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1691325580096", 
      "endTimeMillis": "1685101140000", 
      "description": "", 
      "activityType": 7, 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.xiaomi.hm.health"
      }, 
      "startTimeMillis": "1685100900000", 
      "id": "Walk1685100900000", 
      "name": "Walk"
    }, 
    {
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1691325580096", 
      "endTimeMillis": "1685098020000", 
      "description": "", 
      "activityType": 7, 
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.xiaomi.hm.health"
      }, 
      "startTimeMillis": "1685097600000", 
      "id": "Walk1685097600000", 
      "name": "Walk"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see there is no data from Google Fit app. Should I be performing requests to different endpoint? If so which one